# Payment token not in response

Tags: actions-on-google, google-pay

==== SOLVED ====

Problem is solved. Adyen wants you to send the whole string as an object. JSON.parse(token). Make sure Google pay is enabled in the Adyen platform.

================

I'm working on transactions with Actions on Google and integration Google Pay. I followed all steps according to the documentation of Actions on Google.

To propose an order I send the following snippet seen below.
Notes:

- `gateway` value is replaced for security reasons.
- `gatewayMerchantId` value is replaced for security reasons.
- I'm using a registered gateway.
- I have not yet registered as Google partner though the business console so I have no access to the production API.

```
// Handle order with Google Pay.
conv.ask(new TransactionDecision({
  orderOptions: {
    requestDeliveryAddress: true,
    userInfoOptions: {
      userInfoProperties: [
        'EMAIL',
      ],
    },
  },
  paymentParameters: {
    googlePaymentOption: {
      facilitationSpec: JSON.stringify({
        apiVersion: 2,
        apiVersionMinor: 0,
        environment: 'TEST',
        merchantInfo: {
          merchantName: 'Example Merchant',
          merchantId: '12345678901234567890',
        },
        allowedPaymentMethods: [
          {
            type: 'CARD',
            parameters: {
              allowedAuthMethods: ['PAN_ONLY', 'CRYPTOGRAM_3DS'],
              allowedCardNetworks: [
                'AMEX', 'DISCOVER', 'JCB', 'MASTERCARD', 'VISA',
              ],
            },
            tokenizationSpecification: {
              type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
              parameters: {
                'gateway': 'my_gateway',
                'gatewayMerchantId': 'my_gateway_id',
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        transactionInfo: {
          totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
          totalPrice: prodPriceInclBtwInMicros.toString(),
          currencyCode: 'EUR',
        },
      }),
    },
  },
  presentationOptions: {
    actionDisplayName: 'PLACE_ORDER',
  },
  order: order,
}));
```

The intent that handles the transaction decision value obtains the following `arg` value:

```
    const arg = conv.arguments.get('TRANSACTION_DECISION_VALUE');
```

```
{
'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.actions.transactions.v3.TransactionDecisionValue',
  transactionDecision: 'ORDER_ACCEPTED',
  order: {
    googleOrderId: '02458320178127324049',
    merchantOrderId: 'example',
    userVisibleOrderId: 'example',
    buyerInfo: {
      email: 'example@example.com',
      firstName: 'example',
      lastName: 'example',
      displayName: 'example example'
    },
    createTime: '2020-07-21T10:59:16.624Z',
    lastUpdateTime: '2020-07-21T10:59:16.624Z',
    transactionMerchant: { name: 'Example Merchant' },
    contents: { lineItems: [Array] },
    priceAttributes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    paymentData: { paymentResult: [Object], paymentInfo: [Object] },
    purchase: {
      status: 'CREATED',
      type: 'RETAIL',
      userVisibleStatusLabel: 'CREATED'
    },
    vertical: {
      '@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.actions.orders.v3.verticals.purchase.PurchaseOrderExtension',
      status: 'CREATED',
      type: 'RETAIL',
      userVisibleStatusLabel: 'CREATED'
    }
  }
}
```

According to [Adyen][1] I should provide the payment token: 'Get the token from  PaymentData  response from the Google Pay API.' [Google][2] states that the token will be returned in a response object after the user approves the payment. This is certainly not the case as can be seen in the `arg` object.

By digging deeper into the paymentData, we get the following values:

```
{
  paymentResult: {
    googlePaymentData: '{"signature":"MEYCIQDS8Tiu9bprWqamQ24oNx+Wa43Wg6Vi3sP5PArDeOtOEAIhAOBqe4sQvN5tD390qWzDn9DIgwA8gjS8ajynrusOix6O","protocolVersion":"ECv1","signedMessage":"{\\"encryptedMessage\\":\\"Some_tokens_IUHASIDHUSAGFUAHS\\",\\"ephemeralPublicKey\\":\\"SOMEKEYSASD\\\\u003d\\",\\"tag\\":\\"SOMETAG_OIASJDJSOIJ\\\\u003d\\"}"}'
  },
  paymentInfo: {
    paymentMethodDisplayInfo: {
      paymentType: 'PAYMENT_CARD',
      paymentMethodDisplayName: 'Visa •••• 1234'
    },
    paymentMethodProvenance: 'PAYMENT_METHOD_PROVENANCE_GOOGLE'
  }
}
```

Still no `token` returned in the response... This will be necessary for the gateway.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Or does this have to with the production Transaction API?

Any help is appreciated.
[1]: https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/google-pay/api-only
[2]: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/response-objects#PaymentData

Comment: You need to manually include the token in the additional_params response. You can do that through the customer customer area of your merchant account